understanding sapply and colnames in R programming
I am new to R programming. I am trying to understand the code written by ex-colleague. However, I am facing a difficulty in understanding the below lines. Can you please help in understanding this code line by line.
Please note the ctrlv_sum_outl is a data table in the below code.
for (name in colnames(ctrlv_sum_outl[,sapply(ctrlv_sum_outl, is.character), with=F])){
    Encoding(ctrlv_sum_outl[[name]]) <- "UTF-8"}

ctrlv_sum_IBD = ctrlv_sum_outl[,.(Average_Control_Volume_old = mean(OldControlVolume,na.rm = T), Average_Control_Volume_new = mean(NewControlVolume,na.rm = T)),
                                 by=c("IBD")][order(IBD)]
names(ctrlv_sum_IBD)[1] = "IBD_name"
  


Lets split the code into 3 sections
Loop through character columns only and set encoding to UTF-8.
sapply is identifying character columns only.
colnames is creating a column name vector of character data columns from the dataframe ctrlv_sum_outl.
then in for loop we are encoding the each character
for (name in colnames(ctrlv_sum_outl[,sapply(ctrlv_sum_outl, is.character), with=F])){
  Encoding(ctrlv_sum_outl[[name]]) <- "UTF-8"
}

deriving the new columns (Average_Control_Volume_old, Average_Control_Volume_new) which stores mean or avearge,  by group column IBD
ctrlv_sum_IBD = ctrlv_sum_outl[,.(Average_Control_Volume_old = mean(OldControlVolume,na.rm = T), Average_Control_Volume_new = mean(NewControlVolume,na.rm = T)),
                                 by=c("IBD")][order(IBD)]

renames the first column (which likely contains the original "IBD" names) in ctrlv_sum_IBD to "IBD_name"
names(ctrlv_sum_IBD)[1] = "IBD_name"

